# php - scope issues finding why var is empty on code excerpt

Tags: php, scope, conditional-statements

```
$roidInfo = '';
$nomeDominio ='';
   if (isset($_GET['infoDominio']))
   {
     $nomeDominio = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nomeDominio', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
     $dominioVo->setNome($nomeDominio);
     try 
     {
       ...
      $roidInfo = isset($infoDominio['roid']) ? $infoDominio['roid'] : '';
     }
     catch (EppCommandsExceptions $e)
     {
       ...
     } 

     //all well here, I get the dump with values:
     //var_dump($nomeDominio);
     //var_dump($roidInfo);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['atualizarDominio']))
    {
      var_dump($nomeDominio); //dump ""
      var_dump($roidInfo); //dump ""
```

On the above excerpt I lost the value of $nomeDominio and $roidInfo but I don't understand why. Can I have your help to find out why is this happening?

**UPDATE**

Here is, **the exact same issue**, but by using SESSIONS:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php
 $roidInfo = '';
 $nomeDominio ='';

 if (isset($_GET['infoDominio']))
 {
    $nomeDominio = '123';
    try 
    {
      //...
      $roidInfo = '456';

      $_SESSION['nomeDominio'] = $nomeDominio;
      $_SESSION['roidInfo'] = $roidInfo;

      //retrieving the values. OK.
      var_dump($_SESSION['roidInfo']);
      var_dump($_SESSION['nomeDominio']);
     }
     catch (EppCommandsExceptions $e)
     {
       //...
     }
 }

 if (isset($_POST['atualizarDominio']))
 {
    //retrieving index undefined. not ok.
    var_dump($_SESSION['nomeDominio']);
    var_dump($_SESSION['roidInfo']);


    //all the rest... runs
 }

?>
```

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Comment: Can you confirm 100% that the variables contain something where you say "all well" and they are empty directly afterwards? In the same script call? I's be extremely surprised if that were the case.

Comment: If I need to provide more info, just let me know. :) It should be something really basic. :s

Comment: I am not a PHP expert, but can't it be that $_POST['atualizarDominio'] is set, but $_GET['infoDominio'] is not, so nothing is ever set to $nomeDominio and $roidInfo?

Comment: @Pekka - I will do it right away...

Comment: @Karel Bilek, if I can see the dump after the $_POST it's because it's set so I believe, and, all the code after the $_POST runs.

Comment: @All I will have a test, give me some minutes. (I'm newbie).

Comment: as softcr said. You got two DIFFERENT conditions. one on $_GET['infoDominio'], one on $_POST['atualizarDominio']. Maybe only one of them is set and the other is not?

Comment: @Pekka and All: I have test the dump, exactly where they appear on the excerpt above. I run the first, (I hit "get info button") the dumps shows values. I hit the second ("all runs", but the dump returns are empty).

Comment: MEM: What buttons are you talking about? The script runs at once, and then it forgets all the variables until you run it again. But the script doesn't keep the values between page reloads

Comment: But this was working before. Arrhhgg!!! Yes, I do have two submit buttons, on two different forms. One uses get, the other uses post. one I retrieve information, the other I save information. Yes, I must use the information collected in the first interaction, and have it available on the second... :((

Comment: OK, this is the real problem; PHP forgets all it's variables. But no worries - there is this thing called cookies and sessions. Google them, or look here - http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/0/0

Comment: @Karel Bilek: So either I use a session, or I collect the values again on the first interaction? The issue here is that, on the first interaction, I collect some database values, and I don't want to do that again, so once I receive them, once, I will need to store them, and then retrieve them again. I'm absolutely sure that THIS as worked before, but I have been messed up with something on the way down... :( What are the possibilities?

Comment: Yes, you will have to. You can use both sessions and cookies, depending on what the values are.

Comment: :( k. This is really weird. Without sessions I had this working, I'm almost sure of it. :( Thanks I will see what can I do.

Comment: You probably wrote the first condition wrong and retrieved the values again from the DB. But PHP doesn't hold values between each run of the script.

Comment: @All - I have change $nomeDominio and $roidInfo to work with SESSIONS instead. I store the values on a session on $_GET['infoDominio'] and I try to retrieve them on $_POST['atualizarDominio']. I get undefined index on the later. :(

Comment: Now, that's rude! Given -1 without even asking to be more clear (the effort it's all there) or to justify why it's not useful. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a weird case. I was able do pass the values due to my form action declarations.

I had, on the first form:

```
 <form name="infoDominio" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"  method="get">
```

On the second form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" name="atualizarDominio" method="post">
```

If we remove the action information from the second form:

```
<form action="" name="atualizarDominio" method="post">
```

It will work.

Thank you all that have replied, this is, à mon avis, a weird stuff. :s

Answer (score 0):

Is `isset($_GET['infoDominio']` actually true? If thats not the case `$nomeDominio` stays an empty string in the last code block.

Comment: ? Yes, isset($_GET['infoDominio'] is true, all that is inside runs, and it only runs if it's true, so it's, it's true. Still, I have dump it: bool(true). So yes. All true.

Answer (score 0):

You got two DIFFERENT conditions. one on `$_GET['infoDominio']`, one on `$_POST['atualizarDominio']`. Maybe only one of them is set and the other is not?

The "all well" code is run when `$_GET['infoDominio']` is set. The "not all well" is run when `$_POST['atualizarDominio']` is set. They are two different variables!

edit:

OK, as I found in the discussion under the original original question - the real issue is that PHP doesn't remember `$nomeDominio` and `$roidInfo` between each run of the script - you have to use sessions or cookies to remember them.

Comment: Bilek - What do you suggest in order to prove your assumption? What do I need to test here in order to see if what you are saying is true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited the answer to the actual issue (if I got it right) from the discussion up there

Comment: I've used sessions I still get those values undefined. :( Not been that, what could it be?